# ADODB.Connection wrapper as System.Data.Common.DbConnection

Tags: c#, com, adodb

Is there an easy way to wrap an ADODB.Connection COM object (the one defined in adodb.dll) into a System.Data.Common.DbConnection ?

This connection is created in VBA and I would like to pass it to some C# component that expect System.Data.Common.DbConnection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, you cannot do that. ADO.NET is very different than ADO.